# JSON datatype and text issue from jQuery ajax calls

Tags: jquery, json, mockjax

I am making two ajax calls in one page via jquery.

First one is for autocomplete in jquery mockjax and second one is to get listing data.Both of them conflect with return data.

Here is for autocomple

```
 $.mockjax({
    url: '*',
    responseTime: 2000,
    contentType: "text/json",
    response: function (settings) {
        var query = settings.data.query,//this line give me error
        queryLowerCase = query.toLowerCase(),
            re = new RegExp('\\b' + $.Autocomplete.utils.escapeRegExChars(queryLowerCase), 'gi'),
            suggestions = $.grep(countriesArray, function (country) {
                 // return country.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) === 0;
                return re.test(country.value);
            }),
            response = {
                query: query,
                suggestions: suggestions
            };

        this.responseText = JSON.stringify(response);
```

Here is for listing data

```
  $.getJSON("getname.php?city="+city, function(json){ 
   $.each(json, function (i, item) {
```

Now both of them conflect with return data JSON.

How i can change **JSON** in `$.getJSON`

UPDATE:When i do not use getJSON then no issue,On calling getJSON give me issue

Update: Here is my setting for mockjax

```
    status:       200,
    statusText:   "OK",
    responseTime: 500,
    isTimeout:    false,
    contentType:  'text/plain',
    response:     '',
    responseText: '',
    responseXML:  '',
    proxy:        '',
    proxyType:    'GET',

    lastModified: null,
    etag:         '',
    headers: {
        etag: 'IJF@H#@923uf8023hFO@I#H#',
        'content-type' : 'text/plain'
    }
```

Comment: If you inspect settings, what datatype is it, what about doing a JSON.parse(settings);
var query = settings.data.query;
by the way, I think you have a syntax error in your posted code, a comma on the end of the line...

Comment: why there is a comma at the end, there should be ;

Comment: I update complet autocomplete code,In console i only get this error in red MOCK GET: getname.php.....

Comment: The comma on the end of the line is fine as hes setting multiple variables.

Comment: When i do not use getJSON then no issue,On calling getJSON give me issue

Comment: Still waiting for a proper response..please help me